# Alternative to tf.parallel_stack() for eager execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I'd like to use tf.parallel_stack() for a data operation inside an eagerly-compiled model, but it seems that tf.parallel_stack() doesn't support eager execution. I'm therefore looking for alternative function(s) achieving the same result.

Below is a small example of the required result:

```
x = tf.constant([1, 4])
y = tf.constant([2, 5])
z = tf.constant([3, 6])

# Wanted result:
tf.parallel_stack([x, y, z])  # [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

I tried `tf.concat()`, but I'd still need to convert the resulting 1D vector into a 2-dimensional one as above.

```
tf.concat((x, y, z), axis = 0) # [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Try: `tf.concat((x[None, ...], y[None, ...], z[None, ...]), axis = 0)`

Comment: Oh, of course! (Which I just realised is the same as tf.stack, not sure how I got so confused yesterday.) Feel free to add as an answer & I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try adding a new dimension:

```
tf.concat((x[None, ...], y[None, ...], z[None, ...]), axis = 0)
```